# Find certain value/element in two-dimensional ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have a two dimensional arraylist

```
List<List<String>> movies_info = new ArrayList<>();
```

which I populate creating new rows

```
movies_info.add(new ArrayList<String>());
```

and adding elements

```
movies_info.get(i).add(title);
```

.
I would like to be able to check if the element I'm adding already exist in the entire ArrayList. Is it possible to achieve this result without using the following for.loop?

```
boolean found = false;
for (int i = 0; i < movies_info.size(); i++) {
    if(movies_info.get(i).contain(title)) {
    found = true;
}
if (!found) {
    movies_info.add(new ArrayList<String>());
    movies_info.get(i).add(title);
}
```

Comment: No, it isn't possible without looping or doing something equivalent to the loop (maybe with Java 8).

Comment: I have a higher-order function library that could help you if you don't want to get into streams: https://github.com/smaspe/FunctionalIterables Something like `if (!FuncIter.any(movies_info, list -> list.contains(title))) { movies_info.add(Arrays.asList(title)); }`

Comment: Thanks @LouisWasserman for the clarification. I was expecting that. I suppose I will loop then.

Comment: Why do you need the list of lists?

Answer (score 1):

You can replace your second `ArrayList` by a [HashMap](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_hashmap_class.htm)  and check if it is already there.

```
movies_info.add(new HashMap<String,String>());

if (!movies_info.get(i).containsKey(title)){
    movies_info.get(i).put(title,title);
}
```

Both the search for a key in the `HashMap` and also adding a new element have constant time complexity `O(1)`

To get the values afterwards you can use this code

```
for (String title : movie_info.get(i).keySet()){
      // Use title
}
```

Comment: Also could use a HashSet in there depending on the level of manipulation you are looking for.

Comment: As I answered to @PedroHawk below, my idea was to search in the entire 2D ArrayList at once, without passing by rows.

Comment: Are you worried about memory complexity?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a different approach. Instead of creating a list of lists of `String`-s, you can have a class called `Movie` and create a list of `Movie` objects. Then you can directly query the list by calling the `contains` method.

**Note**: you need to override two methods in the `Movie` class, `hashCode` and `equals`, for the `contains` method to work. By overriding these two methods, you will tell the `list` object how to compare two `Movie` objects.

**UPDATE**: you don't have to manually write the `equals` and `hashCode` methods (at least not if you are using the Eclipse IDE). You can just right-click anywhere inside the class's body and choose `Source -> Generate hashCode and equals ...`, it will prompt you on which fields of the class you want to compare two objects, select the fields, hit **OK** and off you go, these two methods will be automatically generated for you.

Here's a simple example:

```
public class Movie
{
    String title;

    public Movie(String t)
    {
        this.title = t;
    }

    public String getTitle()
    {
        return title;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((title == null) ? 0 : title.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Movie other = (Movie) obj;
        if (title == null)
        {
            if (other.title != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!title.equals(other.title))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

You can test it like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<Movie>();
        movies.add(new Movie("Movie 1"));
        movies.add(new Movie("Movie 2"));

        System.out.println(movies.contains(new Movie("Movie 1")));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? it simplifies a bit..

```
for(List<String> mInfo : movies_info) {
   if(!mInfo.contains(title)) {
      //do stuff
   }
}
```

Comment: The thing you wrote is essentially the same as mine. Just better written. The code still have to iterate through all the rows. Maybe I have not been clear enough. I would like to scan the entire structure of the 2D arraylist at once. Is that possible?